# Thévenin equivalent: is this resistor useless?

Tags: circuit-analysis, sensor, signal-processing, thevenin

I am doing a lab project that includes a sensor connected to a signal conditioning module. I am analyzing the circuit to understand more about how it works and I came across this:

[image]

That voltage source "Sensor" represents the sensor output signal. (My sensor is a LDR/photoresistor. I thought about modelling it as a voltage source because I was measuring its voltage for different illuminations.) Rpol is the polarization resistor, there is a switch that changes it from 100 ohm to 1k ohm.

Anyway I've decided to calculate the Thévenin equivalent circuit of this thing arriving with

$$V_{th}=\frac{R_{25}}{R_{25}+R_{23}}(V_{in}-5)$$

$$R_{th}=R_{23}//R_{25}$$

So... What is the polarization resistor doing there? What is its purpose?

Comment: A photoresistor is a *resistor*, not a voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

If the sensor is a photoresistor it should be modeled as a resistor, because that's what it is, a resistor that varies depending on how much light falls on it.
From the schematic, the LDR forms a voltage divider with Rpol, and it would appear that the voltage across Rpol is what you are reading. The resistance of the LDR changes with light, changing the ratio of the voltage divider, which changes the voltage where R23 connects to them.
Rpol is necessary to form the bottom leg of the voltage divider.

Comment: *From the schematic, the LDR forms a voltage divider with Rpol* … no it doesn’t.

Comment: How does it not? I don't know what goes on off to the right, but from what is shown it's a voltage divider feeding a second voltage divider. Sure the other resistors and whatever else is connected to them could be considered part of the divider with the LDR, but I'm trying to explain the basics of it without being pedantic.

Here's another question on LDRs showing them being used in a voltage divider.

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/7921/why-do-you-need-a-second-resistor-when-using-a-photoresistor-ldr

Comment: Here's the circuit redrawn
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx9TC.jpg

Comment: The combination of R23 in series with R25 is in parallel with Rpol. It's not a case of being pedantic, more to do with being plain wrong.